# How to edit existing VS Code Snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Is there a way to remove or edit some of the default code snippets in Visual Studio CODE ?

For example when i type req+TAB i need `require` not `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64688778/836330 for how to disable/ignore any snippet, built-in or from an extension.

Comment: In my case the C/C++ extension was showing me snippets that I could disable by going to the extension settings and searching for snippets.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The suggestion item `requestAnimationFrame` is coming from the JavaScript language service. **It's not coming from the snippets.**

However, you can define your own snippets and tell Visual Studio Code to show the snippets first. How to do it:

1. Go to `File -> Preferences -> User Snippets` and select *JavaScript* in order to edit snippets for that language
2. Add this entry to the opened file `javascript.json` and save it

   ```
   "require": {
       "prefix": "req",
       "body": [
           "require"
       ],
       "description": "Add 'require'"
   }
   ```
3. Add the following line to your preferred `settings.json` (user or workspace settings) and save it

   ```
   "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
   ```

Now you get your self defined `require` suggestion in first place as soon as you  type `req` in a `.js` file.

Comment: What about code snippets from extensions? Can we modify them?

Comment: This method did not work for me when trying to override a snippet from an extension. If you make your snippet global, it will work though (but then you get "redundant" snippets).

Answer (score 49):

**The extensions snippets can be found inside each snippet directory below:**
*(if there are snippets in the extension)*

**Mac/Linux:  `$HOME/.vscode/extensions/`

Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions/`**

Select the extension you want to modify and then dive into the ***javascript.json*** file in ***snippets/*** directory in there, and change whatever you like.

Just remember that if/when you choose to download and *update* the extension someday, all your personal modifications will get overwritten/replaced out with the updated version of the file.
(unless of course you squirrel away your changes outside of the extension's directory...)

***Edit/Aside:***
Looking closely at all the copied editions already present in this directory, it appears that at least some of the extension updates keep the former version around. If this is the case, when you *update* an extension when a new version is released, you wouldn't need to worry about storing a copy of your modified file somewhere else; returning a file to active duty might just be as easy as a copy-paste from the old into the appropriate, newer, higher numbered directory.

***Resources/citations/acknowledgements:***
Thanks to [here](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/12/16/visual_studio_code_extensions/) for helping initially pointing me towards the relevant directory.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19909566)

Comment: Great advice, thanks!
However, that link is only included as a citation/acknowledgement of resources consulted. All the relevant information is already in my response. Good concern though, and will add a subheading to help better communicate the reason the link is included.

Comment: Since this answer gives tip how to edit existing code snippets in vs code it should be marked as a best one.

Comment: This answer is about extension snippets, not the default snippets which the question was about.  While this answer has useful information, it doesn't really have anything to do with the original question.

Comment: Is there also a way to know "which" extension has added a certain snippet?

Comment: Not worked for c++ snippets.

Answer (score 9):

On my Windows installation the default/built-in JavaScript snippets are located in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript\snippets\javascript.json

I renamed that snippet to "logx" (requires admin privileges to modify the file) and restarted vsCode and now have just my user "log" snippet.

There are some threads about this on the issue tracker -

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10565
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48315

Comment: On Mac its `/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/javascript/snippets/javascript.code-snippets` - you'll have to navigate to the `Visual Studio Code` app and right click to Show Package Contents.

Answer (score 9):

On my Windows10 machine the log and other default javascript snippets can be found in :

`C:\Users\$USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript\snippets\javascript.json`

Answer (score 8):

This is now possible in the latest vscode. Solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10565#issuecomment-721832613

That solution tells you how to disable any snippet (including built-in or extension snippets). While this is technically not editing the snippet, disabling the snippet and then [creating your own user snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) accomplishes the same exact goal. Yay!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for: a way to disable a specific snippet from an extension, and to do that without having to modify the extension. Selecting `Insert Snippet`, typing in the snippet name, then clicking the eye-icon to "Hide from Intellisense" worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found mine at `~/.config/Code/User/snippets`

If you want to create a global snippet, create a file named `snippet_name.code-snippets`

If you want a language specific snippet, create it like `php.json`

Answer (score 1):

Hiding default VSCode snippets is easy:

> you can hide specific snippets from showing in IntelliSense (completion list) by selecting the *Hide from IntelliSense* **button** to the right of snippet items in the *Insert Snippet* **command** dropdown.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_can-i-remove-snippets-from-intellisense