# How to edit the default log snippet in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm using VS Code, and there is a default `log` snippet for JavaScript, that basically adds a `console.log()` line BUT also adds a new blank line.
I want to remove that new blank line.
Do you know how to do it? I only can see the way to modify the User snippets, but this snippet was not created by me

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110541/how-to-edit-existing-vs-code-snippets .  Just make your own snippet and set "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"  You do not want to be editing the built-in snippets.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was slightly answered in other questions but here is my approach anyway.
I wasn't able to configure the default snippets in vscode however I created my own snippet and made it at the top of the suggestions.

1. Go to `File -> Preferences -> User Snippets` and select *JavaScript* in order to edit snippets for that language.
2. Add this entry to the opened file `javascript.json` and save it

> ```
> "Print to console": {
>           "prefix": "log",
>           "scope": "javascript,typescript",
>           "body": [
>               "console.log('$1')",
>           ],
>           "description": "Log output to console"
> },
> ```

then I added

> "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",

in my settings so that it will always be the top suggestion

hope that helps

Comment: Also note that both standard and your custom snippets will be show in suggest.
And if you want your snippet to go above the standard - you can change `description` so that it terms of sort order your `description` comes before standard snippet `description`.

Comment: doesn't really solve the problem and adds clutter to the auto complete.  see answer below for final solution by Filip Van Gench

Answer (score 7):

On my Windows10 machine the log and other default javascript snippets can be found in :

```
C:\Users\$USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript\snippets\javascript.json
```

Comment: works and finally rid of that ugly semi colon!  remember to restart vs code to see the changes