# How to edit a cw snippet in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, code-snippets

I went to xml and until by notepad but when I'm going to save it show me : Access Denied, I went in properties and permissions I selected : Full Control but doesn't work. Someone can help me ? I just want to take out the semicolon from cw, I create a cr that works great but it is in another folder ...

Comment: Start your notepad elevated (with administrator privileges).

Comment: Off-topic, but a hint from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50659099/2590375): be aware, that it *might be* possible, that your custom editation gets reset, if you update your IDE

Comment: Thank you very much René Vogt, you're right and did work ... I could change directly inside XML :)) I take off the parentheses too letting only Console.WriteLine (worked better if  I open myself the parentheses what I input like " or { close too, with the parenthese and semicolon I have to close " and { ... The answer was perfectly right ... Thank u very much !!!