# Modify default C++ snippets in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I would like to modify the default code snippets for C++ in Visual Studio Code. I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110541/how-to-edit-existing-vs-code-snippets), but they actually show how to create your own snippets - and not how to modify the default snippets.

The reason I want to do this is because I'm used to doing some things a bit differently than how they are done in the snippets. For example, this is what appears when I use the `if` snippet:

```
if (/* condition */)
{
    /* code */
}
```

And I would like it to be like this:

```
if(/* condition */){
    /* code */
}
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do? Thank you.

Comment: much easier to make your own snippets because when you update VSC your modified default snippets will be gone

Comment: @rioV8 But then 2 snippets will show up every time I write 'if' and I'll have to select the one I created...

Comment: then prefix your custom snippets with a `c`, instead of `if` type `cif`

Answer (score 2):

1. Press Ctrl + ,(opens vs code settings);
2. Type "snippet" in settings search bar;
3. In Extentions List choose C/C++
4. Untick "Suggest Snippets" button;
5. Close settings tab.
6. Go to settings again and create new User Snippets as you liked.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r1eh.png)