# changing the default settings or formatting of the html skeleton?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I pretty new on these things and im trying to improve my self on html skeleton. So when I call html skeleton on vscode it's being like this as you know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

but i want to change default html skeleton content as like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{background-color: black;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: I believe this may be a duplicate of the post [How to edit existing VS Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110541/how-to-edit-existing-vs-code-snippets).  If not, please clarify what in that post fails to address your issue here.

Answer (score 2):

### **You can make your own custom snippet using vscode.**

As in your case you can create one using the following steps:

- Open the gear icon on the bottom left of you vscode.

[image: img_1]

- Select user snippet
- Type html

### **Adding your custom html skelton**

You can now add this code to have your custom skelton:

```
     "boilerplate": {
        "prefix": "log",
        body: [
                  "<!DOCTYPE html>",
                  "<html lang=\"en\">",
                  "<head>",
                  "    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">",
                  "    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">",
                  "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">",
                  "    <title>Document</title>",
                  "    <style>",
                  "        body{background-color: black;}",
                  "    </style>",
                  "</head>",
                  "<body>",
                  "    ",
                  "</body>",
                  "</html>",
                ],
                "description": ""
              }
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
     }
}
```

I haven't changed the prefix, but it can be changed through `"prefix": ""`

### **Using the custom snippet**

To use the custom snippet, just type the prefix in the html file to get the results!

---

*If you want to add you own custom code, and have problem in converting it into snippet, here's a website which will help in that:*
[snippet  generator](https://snippet-generator.app/)

*For more knowledge this video can help:* [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIqk9UxgKEc)