# How to change the basic html structure in VS code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I would like to change the basic hmtl structure in VS code that is loaded with [! + tab] or [ctrl + space]

What I have when I press [! tab]:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to set it to for example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I tried looking into the html snippets parameters but didn't find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit existing VS Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110541/how-to-edit-existing-vs-code-snippets)

Answer (score 1):

##### To **overwrite** existing **emmets** in VS Code:

1. Create a `snippets.json` file, add this JSON structure and **save** it somewhere on your hard disk.

   ```json
   {
     "html": {
      "snippets": {
        "!": "{<!DOCTYPE html>}+html[lang='fr']>(head>meta:utf+meta:vp+title{${2:Document}}+link[rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'])+body"
      }
    },
    "css": {
      "snippets": {}
    }
   }
   ```
2. Open the VS Code settings (**Code → Preferences → Settings**) and search for “**Emmet Extensions Path**”.

   [image: Search for Emmet Extensions Path]
3. Click “**Add Item**”, enter the path to the folder where you’ve saved the `snippets.json` file you’ve created earlier, and press “OK”.

   [image: add path of the folder]
4. Now try <kbd>!</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> ;)

---

To learn more about how custom snippets work, check [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/06/custom-emmet-snippets-vscode/) article